# Let $f(x), g(x) \in C[x]$. Suppose $f(x) | g(x)$ and let $c \in C$. Prove that if $f(c) = 0$ then $g(c) = 0$. Is the converse true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $f(x), g(x) \in C[x]$. Suppose $f(x) | g(x)$ and let $c \in C$. Prove that if $f(c) = 0$ then $g(c) = 0$. Is the converse true?

What I have so far:

Since $f(x) | g(x)$, $f(x) = g(x)q(x)$ from some $q(x)\in C[x]$. Since $f(c) = 0$, $g(c) q(c) = 0$. I'm having trouble at this part. How do I specifically show $g(c) = 0$ and not $q(c)$?

Comment: If you have $f(x)|g(x)$ then there exists $q(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $g(x)=f(x)\times q(x)$ (your first statement is wrong).

Comment: ah, my mistake. That makes things much simpler. Thank you!